# Why The Stack code have problem in 'P' and 'O'?

Tags: python, data-structures, stack

Why when I write 'P' in this code, it didn't print the List?

```
queue = []

while True:
    order = input("Enter an order: ")
    if order.isalpha():
        queue.append(order)
        print(queue)
    elif order == 'O':
        if len(queue) > 0:
            queue.pop(0)
            print(queue)
    elif order == 'P':
        print(queue)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Check `"P".isalpha()`...

Comment: You need to enter Capital 'P' or 'O'

Answer (score 0):

The 'O' and 'P' characters are being caught by your first condition, `if order.isalpha()`. You should put this one last, since first you want to check if it is equal to 'O' or 'P', then if it is NOT one of those 2 options, then you want to continue to the last condition.

```py
queue = []

while True:
    order = input("Enter an order: ")
    if order == 'O':
        if len(queue) > 0:
            queue.pop(0)
            print(queue)
    elif order == 'P':
        print(queue)
        break
    elif order.isalpha():
        # The input was not O or P, now we will perform logic for other characters
        queue.append(order)
        print(queue)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: THANK YOU but why when i print P the code didn't stop?

Comment: Happy to help :) If you want it to stop when you type `P`, then you need to put the `break` statement inside the `order == 'P'` block.

Comment: THANK YOU bro but can you rewrite the code with last edit

Comment: Gladly. Hope this helped, if my answer was correct please click the check mark on the left :)

Comment: Using `while True:` to loop, then using `break` to stop the loop, makes the code needlessly obfuscated and hard to understand. Instead, use the condition to stop the loop. For instance, `while order.isalpha() and order != 'P':`. This way, the reader understand immediately what will stop the loop.